# Error converting varchar to numeric in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have requirement such that the input parameter which is passed to SP is of type numeric(18,6). And this parameter is passed to the dynamic sql query (type varchar) and the result will be stored to a temp table. In the temp table I hv defined the the above column type as numeric only. but While executing the SP, I am getting "error converting data type varchar to numeric."
Is there in restriction in using dynamic Sql? someone Please help me in this.

sample query:

```
-------------
Input Parameter: @DataItem numeric(18,6) = ABC054356  (column name) 

CREATE TABLE #Temp1(RowNum int, 
                    CompanyID int, 
                    ABCColumn numeric(18,2), 
                    FiscalYear varchar(100))

DECLARE @QUERY varchar(max)

SET @QUERY = N'select row_number() over (partition by fy.keyinstn order by fy.fiscalyear desc) as RowNum, fy.Keyinstn, '
                        + Convert(@DataItem as numeric(18,2)))+
                        ', period.fiscalyear from ABCTable
................
................


INSERT into #Mnemonic
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: What is your sample input values ?

Comment: Convert your numeric type param to string for string concatenation, and then convert to numeric 'SELECT CONVERT(' + Convert(@DataItem as varchar)+ ',NUMERIC(18,2)'

Comment: Here @DataItem = ABC054356 and ABC054356 is numeric(18,6) data type.

Comment: ABC054356 would be the column name and the values will be 1435.8765, 4356.8879, 0.0000....

Comment: You got the syntax for using [CONVERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) wrong. And you should use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) with parameters. To prevent against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. (not sure why you would need the cast just for the order by though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently passing in a *column* name in the table, which you then want to convert.

If so, then this would look like

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'
select row_number() over (partition by fy.keyinstn order by fy.fiscalyear desc) as RowNum,
       fy.Keyinstn,
       convert(decimal(18, 2), [DataItem]) as [DataItem], 
       period.fiscalyear
from ABCTable
. . .
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[DataItem]', @DataItem);

insert into #Mnemonic
    exec(@query);
```

Comment: Do I need to define [DataItem]?

Comment: @Tim . . . No.  The `replace()` replaces it with the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the numeric value to string before concatenation

```
SET @QUERY = N'select row_number() over (partition by fy.keyinstn order by fy.fiscalyear desc) as RowNum, fy.Keyinstn, '
                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DataItem)+
                        ', period.fiscalyear from ABCTable ....... '
```